# Accessing a field in a sub-subquery SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a fairly complex query in which I am working with with multiple nested layers of queries.  One of the requirements of the query is that I access a field from a subquery's subquery in the main query.  However, due to aggregates in the middle query, I can not include the field in that query.

eg.

```
select a, d.x, f.v?
from b
  join (select a, max(z), min(z), Count(y) as x
        from c
          join (select a, Count(t) as v
                from e
               ) f 
            on f.a = c.a
            Group By a
            Having min(z) <> max(z)
       ) d 
     on d.a = b.a
```

Is this possible?

Comment: jas, can you modify your example so, as you say, there's aggregation in the appropriate query?  Basically, if you need to lose it in an inner layer, you won't be able to get it back without exploding the rows back out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Try this instead. Basically, get the attributes you need as you go up hierarchy (may be rename them if needed) and then use them.

```
Select a, d.fa From b
join (select a,f.a fa from c
join (select a from e) f on f.a = c.a
) d on d.a = b.a
```

I don't have test tables yet..If you see any more issues, post them here.

*** Edit Based on updated Question***

Even here, the logic remains the same, you'll have to either use...

```
select a, d.x, d.v?
from b
  join (select a, f.v, max(z), min(z), Count(y) as x
        from c
          join (select a, v
                from e
               ) f 
            on f.a = c.a
            Group By a, f.v
            Having min(z) <> max(z)
       ) d 
     on d.a = b.a
```

Or if your Database supports Scalar sub queries, you can get the value at the final outer Query using..

```
select a, d.x, (select v from e where e.a = b.a) f_v
from b
  join (select a, max(z), min(z), Count(y) as x
        from c
          join (select a, v
                from e
               ) f 
            on f.a = c.a
            Group By a
            Having min(z) <> max(z)
       ) d 
     on d.a = b.a
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I just made an edit
I forget to mention that I can't include the field in the middle query due to aggregates

Comment: Can you modify your query to show how you use aggregates (at least a sample)? The short Answer is no, you cannot access them from 2 levels down, but there is always a work around. :)

Comment: As I said below, I forgot to include that v is in itself an aggregate function, so I can not pass it through as it changes my middle query

Are scalar sub queries supported in sql server?

Comment: Looks like they are.. Check this link.. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3407911/Scalar-Sub-Queries-in-SQL-Server.htm.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably more straight forward if you just bring the table you care about (e in this case) back into the From clause

```
SELECT a, 
       d.x, 
       e.v 
FROM   b 
       JOIN (SELECT a, 
                          MAX(z), 
                          MIN(z), 
                          COUNT(y) AS x 
                   FROM   c 
                          JOIN (SELECT a 
                                FROM   e) f 
                            ON f.a = c.a 
                   GROUP  BY a 
                   HAVING MIN(z) <> MAX(z)) d 
         ON d.a = b.a 
       JOIN (SELECT a, Count(t) as v
            FROM e
            GROUP BY A ) e
         ON e.a = d.a
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that v in itself is an aggregate function, the data in the main query will not return the same values

Comment: @jas I've updated my answer to reflect this change. It seems as though you don't actually use (`Count(t) as v`) inside your `d` subquery. That being the case its probably worthwhile to pull that part out as a separate query